# ASP.Net Good ToolTip for a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tooltip

I search a Script / Expansion / Way to have a tooltip like this:
http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/Untitled37105acbpng.png

That means:
- it must be easy to handle within GridViews (specially in RowBound-Events, so every Row will have a own Tooltip for a coloum).
- Must be have the option for delay when hover over the item (I don't like the default ASP.ToolTip because you can't set the delay down!)

Hoe you have an idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use f.e. [this jQuery plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/).
Here are some links to get started:

- [Using jQuery To Create Stunning Tooltips in your ASP.NET Applications](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=395)
- [Displaying-Row-Details-Tooltip-on-GridView-using-JQuery](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Displaying-Row-Details-Tooltip-on-GridView-using-JQuery.aspx)